# How to define a style for all the elements inside a parent element?

Tags: html, css

I have some structure like this....

```
<div class="pull-right visible-xs col-xs-4 text-xs-center menu_bars">
                    <p style="margin: 10px;">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                    </p>
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </div>
```

I want to define style `cursor:pointer` for all the `<i>` under the class `menu_bars`.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.menu_bars i {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS code block:

```
.menu_bars i {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: sorry i didnt mentioned it....i just want to have the cursor:pointer for the <i> element not for the others...

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
.menu_bars i {
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.menu_bars i{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using css, you can use class selector.
in the css file (or in css script):

```css
.menu_bars{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="pull-right visible-xs col-xs-4 text-xs-center menu_bars">
                    <p style="margin: 10px;">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x">Text Here</i>
                    </p>
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </div>
```